# get/set properties not yet supported by flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is the following unsupported by flow?

```
/* @flow */

module.exports = {
    get rules() {
        return require("./rules").default;
    }
}
```

Why I am getting `get/set properties not yet supported by flow` locally and made it work [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVZNgLZwCYCuMApgHTEAeADnAE4AuAzmALxgDeGWAkAObH0wtIsUYAKAJQcumbt1oCCtAHZgARIzjYBACwCWy3moDcMsNwC+Zq0A)?

**Note:** Using flow-bin v0.60.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of flow since `unsafe.enable_getters_and_setters` is set to true by default.